# Calculo Incorreto

Tags: javascript, node.js

Olá,

Gostaria de saber o porque no javascript:

```
console.log(500 - (400 * 1.1))
```

O resultado deveria ser 60, mas o resultado é 59.99999999999994.

E como resolver.

Comment: Complementando o link já indicado acima no box azul, tem outros [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8678/112052) que também explicam o problema. Quanto a solução correta, depende muito de cada caso. Nesse, por exemplo, poderia arredondar o valor: `500 - Math.floor(400 * 1.1)`

Comment: Você pode utilizar funções para trabalhar com arredondamento.

Comment: valeu gente, usei o toFixed()